# What is the best practice for accessing the value of an associated entity in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Using Doctrine's entity framework, let's assume you have an entity called `$user` that has an OneToOne association with an `$address` entity. The city is stored in the address entity, not in the user entity.

I understand that you can access the value of an associated entity like this:

```
$user_city = &$user->getAddress()->getCity();
```

Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-related-objects

If you need to access the user's city multiple times in the code, is it best to assign this value to a variable (like above with or without the ampersand reference)? Or is it best to just call the entity value via the entire chain `$user->getAddress()->getCity()` every time?

Is the `$user->getAddress()` stored in the $user entity after the first time it's called, and so all it's properties are accessible from now on without any overhead?

What is the standard practice and which is most efficient over the long run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$address` is a separate entity, it means that it have its own lifecycle and whether you save it in a separate variable or not, Doctrine will handle all operations on it properly. Doctrine is using a design pattern called Identity Map (more here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html ) which guarantees you that until you explicitly `clone` it, it will always return the same object. From that link:

> In this case the Article is accessed from the entity manager twice,
>   but modified in between. Doctrine 2 realizes this and will only ever
>   give you access to one instance of the Article with ID 1234, no matter
>   how often do you retrieve it from the EntityManager and even no matter
>   what kind of Query method you are using (find, Repository Finder or
>   DQL). This is called “Identity Map” pattern, which means Doctrine
>   keeps a map of each entity and ids that have been retrieved per PHP
>   request and keeps returning you the same instances.

As for the "best practice", laws of software design apply. If only thing you need is address, pass only address object. If you're operating on whole user, pass user object. Follow `Dependency Injection` and `Law of Demeter` principles and you'll be good.

Also `&` operator is not necessary here as all objects in PHP are passed by reference.

Comment: So it sounds like there is no extra overhead calling $this->getAddress() multiple times. But regarding my specific question, is it better to save the city value to `$user_city` for use later, or to use the entire path `$user->getAddress()->getCity()` each time? Or is it virtually the same thing? It seems like referencing the variable directly would be faster, whereas calling the whole path requires several functions to run in order to return the value. (BTW, as a new member I am not permitted to do much, e.g. upvote your answer...)

Comment: Yep, database is called once, from there on there is only "language" performance penalty which is negligible - how many times in a request are you calling that method? If not thousands, you won't optimize anything. As for the calling code - they're equivalent, use what you like more.